# Why custom delegate in iOS is not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-playground

I am trying to create a custom delegate using playground in swift. However the ***doSomething*** method is not being called through callback.
It seems that ***delegate?.doSomething()*** does not fire to the ***XYZ*** class ***doSomething*** method.
Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol RequestDelegate
{
    func doSomething();

      optional  func requestPrinting(item : String,id : Int)
}


class ABC
{
    var delegate : RequestDelegate?
     func executerequest() {

        delegate?.doSomething()
        println("ok delegate method will be calling")
    }
}   

class XYZ : RequestDelegate
{  
    init()
    {
        var a  = ABC()
        a.delegate = self
    }

     func doSomething() {
       println("this is the protocol method")
    }
}    

var a = ABC()
a.executerequest()
```

Comment: Because the delegate of ABC is nil for the second instance of `var a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems that `delegate?.doSomething()` does not fire to the XYZ class
>   `doSomething` method.

That is correct. `class ABC` has an optional `delegate` property, but the value of
the property is nowhere set. So the `delegate` is `nil`
and therefore the *optional chaining*

```
delegate?.doSomething()
```

simply does nothing. Also you have defined a `class XYZ` but
not created any instances of that class.

If you set the delegate of `a` to an instance of `XYZ` then
it will work as expected:

```
var a = ABC()
a.delegate = XYZ()
a.executerequest()
```

Comment: is this neccessary allways create function like executerequest()// could i call delegate function within viewDidLoad()